# How do I call a function that includes Graphics g

Tags: java, swing

I was wondering how I could call a function that includes Graphics G if a certain thing happens in my program.

```
public void dead (Graphics g) {
    right = false;
    left = false;
    up = false;
    down = false;
    dead = true;
    score = 0;
    moves = 0;
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 50));
    g.drawString("Game Over", 300, 300);

    g.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
    g.drawString("Press \"Space\" To Restart", 312, 340);
}
```

How do I call this from somewhere else? I tried doing dead(); but it says that this method is not vailable for this argument. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here is my JFrame:

```
    JFrame obj = new JFrame("Snake");
    gameplay gameplay = new gameplay(); 
    obj.setBounds(10, 10, 905, 700);
    obj.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    obj.setResizable(false);
    obj.setVisible(true);
    obj.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    obj.add(gameplay);
```

Comment: If this is a Swing GUI (you don't say, but should since this is key information), then this should be called from with a paintComponent method override of a JComponent or JPanel. Please see: [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Comment: can you show us your code when you call the method?

Comment: Well, you need to have something to paint to, which would then depend on the rest of the code

Comment: I just added my JFrame

Comment: Read the tutorials, including the one I linked to. It will explain all. Hopefully your gameplay class (which should be renamed GamePlay) extends JPanel, and you've overridden its paintComponent method. Call your `dead(...)` method in there. Don't forget to call the super's method. Don't call `setVisible(true)` on the JFrame until **after** you've added everything to it.

Comment: Ok thanks, quick question what does the super's method do? I will look over the lesson in full detail after I do something real quick

Comment: The tutorial will explain this

Comment: Please do not do `gameplay gameplay`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This dead(g) method us supposed to be called in `paintComponent(Graphics g)` to update the screen when the snake is dead:

In the panel displaying your paintings, you will have something like this:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g):
    if(gameOver)
        dead(g);
}
```

By the way, you may not want to include codes non-related to painting into your dead(g) method such as:

```
right = flase:
left = flase;
...
score = 0;
moves = 0;
```

Whenever possible, keep your painting methods clutter free from other non-painting related codes. In extreme cases, cluttering it may cause your display to lag.

Comment: Thank you! I just figured out that it wasn't even necessary for me to call an external function but you helped me think of a solution to my problem and taught me something so this was very useful :)